# Is there any difference in the power, wheel, and track technology between 2018 trains and 2022 trains?

Tags: motor, trains, powered-up, tracks

LEGO came out with [60197 City Passenger Train](https://brickset.com/sets/60198-1/Cargo-Train) and [60198 City Cargo Train in 2018](https://brickset.com/sets/60198-1/Cargo-Train). Much more recently they released very similar sets [60337 City Express Passenger Train](https://brickset.com/sets/60337-1/Express-Passenger-Train) and [60336 City Freight Train](https://brickset.com/sets/60336-1/Freight-Train). All four sets have the same "Powered Up" logo on the front and look fairly similar.

Are there any differences in the power, wheel, and track technology between these older sets and the new ones? If so, are their obvious pros and cons of these old versus newer train sets?

Answer (score 9):

Most of essential bits are the same and used in all 4 sets:

- [Train motor](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6214559)
- [Straight track](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6070018)
- [Track switch](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6085188)
- [Driving wheels attached to motor](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6284110)

The only difference is in wheel used for cars. Instead of using two [wheels](https://brickset.com/parts/4496343/train-wheel-%C3%B816-6-%C3%B823) attached to metal rod (this combination is then mounted together to [bogie](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-287826)) TLG switched to [wheels](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6253473) that are now attached individually to a different, but similarly looking, [bogie](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6253474).

There was a bit of disappointment and a lot of talks within community about new wheels as they are seen as higher friction option, reducing the performance of (long) trains.